# Cells.value doesn't display any value in a msgBox in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new with VBA and I'm trying to display the value of cells in msgBox (one after another) when looping through a given column, but the message boxes does not show the values (these ones are not empty or "" in the worksheet).

My code is the following:

```
For i=2 To workbooks(filename).Worksheets(1).Columns(columnNumber).rows.count
    MsgBox "Cell value is: " & Cells(i, columnNumber).address 
    MsgBox "Cell value is: " & Cells(i, columnNumber).value
Next i
```

The problem is that the addresses are correctly displayed in the MsgBoxes while the values are not. any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you're referring to the correct sheet? (the address would be the same regardless but of course the value may be very different)

Comment: I said correct sheet, not correct workbook. ;) Try a `Msgbox Cells(i, columnnumber).worksheet.name`

Comment: When you type `workbooks`, `rows`, `count`, `address` or `value`, the Editor will automatically capitalise them.  How have you created this code snippet?

Comment: As @Rory stated, in front of the `Cells(...` try putting, `workbooks(filename).Worksheets(1).`  This will ensure that you are referencing the correct sheet with the msgbox.

Comment: @TonyDallimore: yes they are capitalized in the editor and it is not the problem. to answer your question: i wrote it (no copied it from my editor). I corrected them now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was actually the reference to the correct workbook that was missing. Thanks Rory for your help.

The correct code is as follow:

```
For i=2 To Workbooks(filename).Worksheets(1).Columns(columnNumber).Rows.Count
   MsgBox "Cell value is: " & Workbooks(filename).Worksheets(1).Cells(i, columnNumber).Address 
   MsgBox "Cell value is: " & Workbooks(filename).Worksheets(1).Cells(i, columnNumber).Value
Next i
```

Now it works perfectly.